# IronPython Click Event fire procedure in module

Tags: events, module, click, ironpython

I am getting an error trying to attach a procedure within a module to a TextChanged event.
[image]

Attach event code:

```
import NewMortgage
txtNewMortgageValue = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(_tikitSender,'txtLoanAmount')
txtNewMortgageValue.TextChanged += NewMortgage.evtMortgage_RecalcNet
```

Module NewMortgage.py:

```
def evtMortgage_RecalcNet(sender, e):
   MessageBox.Show('test')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the LogicalTreeHelper functionality into the module, then the event code was accessible.

I also created a Global module to hold frequently used vars.

I first include the modules

```
 import leanGlobal
 import leanNewMortgage
```

Below is the leanNewMortgage module, the instance of class created at the bottom of file.

Notice this module also has 'import leanGlobal' so I can get access to the global vars and functions.

```
###### NEW MORTGAGE FUNCTIONS & VARS ###### 
from System.Windows import MessageBox
from System.Windows import LogicalTreeHelper
import leanGlobal

class NewMortgage(object):
def Init(self):
  self.txtLoanAmount = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(leanGlobal.oGlobal.Sender, 'txtLoanAmount')
  self.txtLenderChaps = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(leanGlobal.oGlobal.Sender, 'txtLenderChaps')
  self.txtCashBack = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(leanGlobal.oGlobal.Sender, 'txtCashBack')
  self.txtRetention = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(leanGlobal.oGlobal.Sender, 'txtRetention')
  self.txtNETAdvance = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(leanGlobal.oGlobal.Sender, 'txtNETAdvance')
  self.AddEvents()

def AddEvents(self):
    self.RemoveEvents()
    self.txtLoanAmount.TextChanged += self.evtMortgage_RecalcNet
    self.txtLenderChaps.TextChanged += self.evtMortgage_RecalcNet
    self.txtCashBack.TextChanged += self.evtMortgage_RecalcNet
    self.txtRetention.TextChanged += self.evtMortgage_RecalcNet

def RemoveEvents(self):
    self.txtLoanAmount.TextChanged -= self.evtMortgage_RecalcNet
    self.txtLenderChaps.TextChanged -= self.evtMortgage_RecalcNet
    self.txtCashBack.TextChanged -= self.evtMortgage_RecalcNet
    self.txtRetention.TextChanged -= self.evtMortgage_RecalcNet

def evtMortgage_RecalcNet(self,sender, e):
    self.RemoveEvents()
    if (self.txtLoanAmount.Text==""):
        self.txtLoanAmount.Text="0"
    if (self.txtLenderChaps.Text==""):
        self.txtLenderChaps.Text="0"
    if (self.txtCashBack.Text==""):
        self.txtCashBack.Text="0"
    if (self.txtRetention.Text==""):
        self.txtRetention.Text="0"
    self.txtNETAdvance.Text=(float(self.txtLoanAmount.Text.replace(',', ''))
            -float(self.txtLenderChaps.Text.replace(',', ''))
            +float(self.txtCashBack.Text.replace(',', ''))
            -float(self.txtRetention.Text.replace(',', ''))).ToString()  
    self.AddEvents()

NewMortgage.txtLoanAmount=object
NewMortgage.txtLenderChaps=object
NewMortgage.txtCashBack=object
NewMortgage.txtRetention=object
NewMortgage.txtNETAdvance=object

oNewMortgage=NewMortgage()
```

I create the Global class first:

```
leanGlobal.oGlobal.Init(_tikitEntity,_tikitMatter.ToString(),_tikitDbAccess,_tikitSender)
```

then I call the calc module(leanNewMortgage.py), and all works OK

```
 leanNewMortgage.oNewMortgage.Init()
```

Notice I also add events, and also temporarily remove them when fired.
This is because I wanted a central event rather than creating an event for every textbox.  As the event modifies the textboxes the events need to be temporarily disabled, otherwise an infinite loop will occur!

The main lesson for me, relating to the question was how to create a tidy program structure.

Whilst I an new  to IronPython I am happy with the structure but would love to hear any comments.